# How do I prove type-level list properties in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, proof, type-level-computation

I have these type families:

```hs
type family xs ++ ys where
  '[]      ++ ys = ys
  (x : xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)

type family Drop n xs where
  Drop  O         xs  = xs
  Drop (S n) (_ : xs) = Drop n xs

type family Length xs where
  Length '[] = O
  Length  (x : xs) = S (Length xs)
```

At some point, GHC wants a proof that

```hs
forall a. Drop (Length a) (a ++ c) ~ c
```

I've used to shove that into context of some constructor.

How do I prove this property universally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so your type families are fine and your property is almost right.

What you want to prove is this:

```hs
proof :: Drop (Length a) (a ++ c) :~: c
```

Except you don't really know what `a` and `c` are. They are implicitly quantified. You want them to be explicit so we can do induction over them.

```hs
proof :: (a :: [ k ]) -> (c :: [ k ]) -> Drop (Length a) (a ++ c) :~: c
```

You'll realise this is not going to type check because Haskell doesn't have real dependent types, but there is a way around: *singleton types*. The idea is to create an indexed type so that each term corresponds to one term of a different type that is used as the type index. I know this sounds a bit confusing, but example should clarify it.

You can use the `singletons` library or build them from scratch that's what I'll do here.

```hs
data family Sing (x :: k)

data SList xs where
  SNil  :: SList '[]
  SCons :: Sing x -> SList xs -> SList (x ': xs)
```

Here `Sing` is a data family so that I can generically refer to things that have singletons. `SList` is the singleton version of the list type and as you can see the `SNil` constructor corresponds to the type-level `[]`. Similarly, `SCons` reflects `:`.

Then (assuming you also have a definition of `data Nat = O | S Nat` somewhere) the signature of the proof you are after is

```hs
proof :: SList a -> SList c -> Drop (Length a) (a ++ c) :~: c
```

Notice that I changed your `~` into a `:~:` that's a type operator available in `Data.Type.Equality`. It's only constructor is `Refl` which you can only assert if its two operands are exactly the same.

Now we just need to prove it. Luckily, this is a super simple property to prove, you just need to do induction over `SList a`

In the base case `SList a` is `SNil`, so you are really trying to prove `Drop (Length '[]) ('[] '++ c) :~: c`. Because you used type families, the type checker will immediately reduce this to `c :~: c`. Since both operands are the same we can use the `Refl` constructor to prove this case.

```hs
proof SNil _ = Refl
```

Now comes the inductive case. We'll pattern match again and this time learn that `SList a` is of the form `SCons a as` with `a :: Sing x` and `as :: Sing xs`. This means what we need to prove is `Drop (Length (x ': xs)) ((x : xs) ++ c) :~: c`. Again your type families will immediately start doing computation and reduce this goal to `Drop (Length xs) (xs ++ c) :~: c` because it doesn't really need to know what `x` is to do the evaluation.

As it turns out, `proof as c` (nb. I use `as` instead of `SCons a as`) has exactly the required type, so we use that to prove the property.

Here's the full proof.

```hs
proof :: SList a -> SList c -> Drop (Length a) (a ++ c) :~: c
proof SNil _ = Refl
proof (SCons a as) cs = proof as cs
```

For these to work, you'll need all of these language extensions:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
```

Comment: You don't use the `SList c` anywhere, btw.

Comment: ...although after playing with an alternate solution a bit: perhaps `SList c` (or even `slist c`) makes avoiding ambiguities easier for callers!

Comment: There is one small issue: you can't construct `SList [Void]` (with the usual definition of `Sing Void` present in the `singletons` package). I would suggest changing the second constructor to use a `Proxy x` instead of `Sing x`

Comment: @DanielWagner yes, technically we can get rid of it, but in practice it just means replacing it with lots of `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications` usage.